# How to install Android Studio from cli

Tags: android, bash, macos, android-studio, curl

I am curling the latest Android Studio dmg file, mounting the image and copying the .app directory into the Applications directory. When I attempt to open the directory I receive this warning, and when I query the application state, I also receive the code below. Any idea how I can generically install Android Studio from the cli?

Warning:
"Android Studio" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash. Google Chrome.app downloaded this file on

...

```
| => spctl -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/
/Applications/Android Studio.app/: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

...

```
| => codesign --display --verbose=4 /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/
Executable=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier=com.google.android.studio
Format=app bundle with Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=537 flags=0x0(none) hashes=11+3 location=embedded
OSPlatform=36
OSSDKVersion=657664
OSVersionMin=657408
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=4456b3e77035b4318af16276667c88f7b7d4f9ac
CandidateCDHash sha256=6d95335c6815111d93abd1e87b9fd4648d991bdd
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash=6d95335c6815111d93abd1e87b9fd4648d991bdd
Signature size=8948
Authority=Developer ID Application: Google, Inc. (EQHXZ8M8AV)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Dec 1, 2016, 4:57:25 PM
Info.plist entries=22
TeamIdentifier=EQHXZ8M8AV
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=11250
Internal requirements count=1 size=188
```

---

Android Install Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Installing Android Studio"

ANDROID_STUDIO_DMG=$(curl -0 https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html | grep -o --regexp='https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*/android-studio-ide-[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*-mac.dmg')

./dmginstall.sh $ANDROID_STUDIO_DMG
```

DMG Install Script - (Modified:https://gist.github.com/rahulgautam/6695872)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Downloads and install a .dmg from a URL
#
# Usage
# $ dmginstall [url]
#
# For example, for installing android-studio-ide
# $ dmginstall https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.2.3.0/android-studio-ide-145.3537739-mac.dmg
#
# TODO
# - currently only handles .dmg with .app folders, not .pkg files
# - handle .zip files as well


if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: dmginstall [url]"
  exit 1
fi

url=$*

# Generate a random file name
tmp_file=/tmp/`openssl rand -base64 10 | tr -dc '[:alnum:]'`.dmg

# Download file
echo "Downloading $url..."
curl -# -L -o $tmp_file $url

echo "Please copy and paste the Volumes directory you would like to use"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
hdiutil mount $tmp_file

IFS= read -r -p "Enter volume: " volume
echo "$volume"

# Locate .app folder and move to /Applications
app=`find "$volume" -name *.app -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0`
echo "Copying `echo $app | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` into /Applications..."
cp -rv "$app" '/Applications'

# Unmount volume, delete temporal file
echo "Cleaning up..."
hdiutil unmount "$volume"
rm "$tmp_file"

echo "Done!"
```

Comment: What were the exact commands you used to mount and copy the package?

Comment: @JosephMCasey : Were you able to install successfully? I am looking for the same thing here :-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672879/installing-android-studio-dmg-through-shell-script-doesnt-work

Comment: @icodes The possibility of using a preconfigured virtual environment was proposed for my particular use case. I could never reliably automate the download and install.

Comment: @JosephMCasey :Hmm.... In my case, the files do get copied to the Applications folder.But the application doesn't launch by clicking on it?...Was that the same case with you?

Comment: I forget @icodes